# What is the global attribute of a network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, ipconfig

I saw the following line of code in a code repo I work on:

```
ip addr | grep 'inet .*global' | cut -f 6 -d ' ' | cut -f1 -d '/' | head -n 1
```

I want to understand what does the "global" attribute mean as part of the network interface attribute?

I hope i am asking it in the right place...

Thanks a lot, Matan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it occur to you to just run the line?

```
$ ip addr | grep 'inet .*global'
inet xx.xx.xx.xx/24 brd xx.xx.xx.255 scope global eth0
```

So, we are talking about the "scope" of the interface here, a term you could just google, which might end you up [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html), explaining

> The possible values for scope are outlined in the following table.
>
> ```
> Table C.2. IP Scope under ip address
> Scope Description
> global    valid everywhere
> site  valid only within this site (IPv6)
> link  valid only on this device
> host  valid only inside this host (machine)
> ```
>
> Scope is normally determined by the ip utility without explicit use on
>   the command line. For example, an IP address in the 127.0.0.0/8 range
>   falls in the range of localhost IPs, so should not be routed out any
>   device. This explains the presence of the host scope for addresses
>   bound to interface lo. Usually, addresses on other interfaces are
>   public interfaces, which means that their scope will be global. We
>   will revisit scope again when we discuss routing with ip route, and
>   there we will also encounter the link scope.